# Fixed text position using an ImageView within PyQtGraph & PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQtGraph and PySide2 to display flat 2D images and 2D slices of 3D volumes (CT/MRI volume datasets etc.) where the user can pan/zoom, scroll etc.

What I would like to do is have text in a few locations within the view, overlying the image, for example in the corner- somewhere I can specify.
I want this text to maintain its screen position, regardless of image pan/zoom etc.
I also want to live update some of this text as the user makes viewing changes (e.g. viewing parameters such as pixel size)

As far as I can see, the most appropriate option is a LegendItem.  There are problems-

- How can I disable user-dragging?
- How do I control text position? the .setPos() method has no effect.
- How do I remove/hide the line to the left of the legend text?

The alternative would be a LabelItem or TextItem, though I can't find a way to assign a *screen* position as opposed to an *image* location. ie- how would I specify *bottom left corner of view window* as opposed to bottom left of *image* - because of course, the image can move.

-Is there a way of fixing the Label/Text position relative to the viewport?

Interestingly the LabelItem pans & zooms with the image, whereas the TextItem only pans with the image.

Here is my minimum working code with examples of each text thing.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout

import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.cw.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cw.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.DcmImgWidget = MyImageWidget(parent=self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.DcmImgWidget)

        self.show()


class MyImageWidget(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, view=pg.PlotItem())

        self.ui.histogram.hide()
        self.ui.roiBtn.hide()
        self.ui.menuBtn.hide()

        plot_view = self.getView()
        plot_view.hideAxis('left')
        plot_view.hideAxis('bottom')

        # 50 frames of 100x100 random noise
        img = np.random.normal(size=(50, 100, 100))
        self.setImage(img)

        text0 = pg.LabelItem("this is a LabelItem", color=(128, 0, 0))
        text0.setPos(25, 25)  # <---- These are coords within the IMAGE
        plot_view.addItem(text0)

        text1 = pg.TextItem(text='This is a TextItem', color=(0, 128, 0))
        plot_view.addItem(text1)
        text1.setPos(75, -20)  # <---- These are coords within the IMAGE

        legend = plot_view.addLegend()
        style = pg.PlotDataItem(pen='w')
        legend.addItem(style, 'legend')


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a QLabel to the viewport of the QGraphicsView used by ImageView:

```py
class MyImageWidget(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, view=pg.PlotItem())

        self.ui.histogram.hide()
        self.ui.roiBtn.hide()
        self.ui.menuBtn.hide()

        plot_view = self.getView()
        plot_view.hideAxis("left")
        plot_view.hideAxis("bottom")

        # 50 frames of 100x100 random noise
        img = np.random.normal(size=(50, 100, 100))
        self.setImage(img)

        label = QLabel("this is a QLabel", self.ui.graphicsView.viewport())
        label.move(25, 25)
```

Comment: Thanks _again_ eyllanesc! Your solution sidesteps the pyqtgraph side nicely. Updating the label.move() method within a resizeEvent updates locations relative to the corners nicely as well.